# shiny navbarMenu for subsidiaries

Tags: r, shiny

```
library(shiny)

 shinyUI(
   navbarPage("Page Title",

    tabPanel("Panel1"),
    tabPanel("Panel2"),
    navbarMenu(
       tabPanel("Panel 3.1"),
       tabPanel("Panel 3.2")))
```

The above is a template. If I want to add two sub panels Panel 3.1.1 and Panel 3.1.2 under Panel 3.1 using the navigation style as navbarMenu, which means when I click Panel 3.1, there will be a drop down list of Panel 3.1.1 and Panel 3.1.2
Didn't figure out how to attain the goal. Is there any suggestions?